# Android- Data not being sent to Server - Volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I am trying to send data to server using volley i am facing this error from a long time.Please let me know how to resolve this??

> 03-11 12:36:26.701 27137-28232/com.ativaishna.av.audb I/System.out:
>   (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false 03-11 12:36:26.701
>   27137-28232/com.ativaishna.av.audb I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static:
>   isShipBuild true 03-11 12:36:26.701 27137-28232/com.ativaishna.av.audb
>   I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Thread-64041-60099235: SmartBonding Enabling
>   is false, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false 03-11
>   12:36:26.701 27137-28232/com.ativaishna.av.audb I/System.out:
>   (HTTPLog)-Thread-64041-60099235: SMARTBONDING_FEATURE_ENABLED is true
>   03-11 12:36:26.701 27137-28232/com.ativaishna.av.audb I/System.out:
>   (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false 03-11 12:36:26.701
>   27137-28237/com.ativaishna.av.audb I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static:
>   isSBSettingEnabled false 03-11 12:36:26.701
>   27137-28237/com.ativaishna.av.audb I/System.out:
>   KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false 03-11
>   12:36:26.701 27137-28232/com.ativaishna.av.audb I/System.out:
>   KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false 03-11
>   12:36:26.701 27137-28248/com.ativaishna.av.audb E/Volley: [64056]
>   NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int
>   java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
>                                                                   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int
>   java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
>                                                                       at libcore.net.UriCodec.encode(UriCodec.java:132)
>                                                                       at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:57)
>                                                                       at com.android.volley.Request.encodeParameters(Request.java:450)
>                                                                       at com.android.volley.Request.getBody(Request.java:436)
>                                                                       at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.addBodyIfExists(HurlStack.java:260)
>                                                                       at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.setConnectionParametersForRequest(HurlStack.java:234)
>                                                                       at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:107)
>                                                                       at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
>                                                                       at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)

Comment: improved format in your question please...

Comment: error message sugests that URL you trying to call is null. Volley is open source, so you can easily get a source code, integrate it into your IDE and debug the error in source code.

Comment: I am trying to send array of data ,using for loop i am calling the volley, its worked for the first time from second time its showing this error. each time volley is called this error is displayed

Comment: Can you show your source and the URL which you're using.

Comment: Pls pay attention to "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object..."

Answer (score 2):

Yes  **I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false** is  issue with specific device most probably Samsung lollipop. Please place all type of network permission in Android Menifest file like:
 `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />`

then uninstall app and reinstall again.

Answer (score 0):

I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false is an issue with specific Samsung devices.If you are already given all type of network permission in Android Manifest file then you can try targetSdkVersion 27.

```
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.gstapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```